# setTimeout not working only for the first time of the event causing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, blur

In code below, i want to set `var hasFocus=False;` after 500ms on blur of mentioned `<textarea>` and `<input>`. This code immediately turns `hasFocus=False` without waiting for 500ms for the first time. Afterwards, it works as expected.
I'm unable to understand why it is not running as expected for the first time only!

```
$(function(){
    var hasFocus=false;

    $("textarea[name='question1'], input[name^=q1_option]").blur(function(event){
        setTimeout(function(){
            hasFocus=false;
        },500);
    }).focus(function(){
       hasFocus=true;
    });

    $(document).on('click',function(e){
        console.log("focus :" +hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus)
        {
           alert("Working!!"); //Now this does not come up for the first time!
        } 
    })
});
```

Comment: You sure it's not the `var hasFocus = false;` right there at the top?

Comment: What do you mean by `code immediately turns hasFocus=False`? You set the variable to `var hasFocus=false;` in second line of your code. What value do you expect `hasFocus` to have?

Comment: @dotnetom you have to focus it before you're able to blur it!

Comment: @Chev  I may be wrong but what i'm doing is setting it false initially and then true on focus of the textarea. Now that it is true, when blur from the textarea happens, it should turn back to False but after 500ms.

Comment: @Tushar try changing your `.focus(function()` to `.click(function()` it may be browser incompatibilities.

Comment: @AaronGillion I thought the same way initially but i've tried this on Chrome and Firefox both and moreover, it doesn't look like browser incompatibilities to me. Anyways, i'll try what you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @TusharShukla Well then I don't see a problem. Here's a demo of your code working fine: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/xZJrOx. You should note that 500 milliseconds is really fast. That's half a second.

Comment: @dotnetom i'm  setting `hasFocus` false initially and then true on focus of the textarea. Now that it is true, when blur from the textarea happens, it should turn back to False but after 500ms. By `code immediately turns hasFocus=False`, i mean that it is not working as expected for the first time only. Works fine afterwards. (When i again focus on textarea and blur it!)

Comment: I can see all alerts - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/c25xphd0/. The first is fired when you focus the textarea for the first time. And the second fires on blur because you set `hasFocus` to false after a timeout. And you can notice that hasFocus turns false after you close the second alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a lot of headbanging, i came up with this. Its not my exact code but a demo and it worked exactly the way i wanted:

```
 $(function(){
    var hasFocus=false;

    $("textarea[name='question1'], input[name^=q1_option]").blur(function(event){
        setTimeout(function(){
            hasFocus=false;
        },500);
    }).focus(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){ //just initiated focus event after blur event
              hasFocus=true; //just initiated focus event after blur event
          },510); //just initiated focus event after blur event
    });

    $(document).on('click',function(e){
        console.log("focus :" +hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus)
        {
           alert("Working!!"); //Now this does not come up for the first time!
        } 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `console.log` executes before the timed out blur event is triggered and thus console shows the previous value. Move the `console.log("focus :" +hasFocus);` inside your `blur` and `focus` functions to see that everything works properly.

Demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/c25xphd0/)

Comment: I totally agree with your answer and i also tried this in my code but it is not working in my case. Apart from this, i just updated my code to show exactly what i'm doing. There is nothing else in my code yet this is occurring. Anything else you that you can suggest? Thanks for you time!

Comment: I've just added the comment to your question and updated fiddle. It works fine there, agree?

Comment: Yes i do, guess i have to scratch my head more, since there is not much code, there must be some silly error. Its just hiding from me :/ Thanks again!

Comment: How do you notice that `code immediately turns hasFocus=False` ? Do you see an immediate message in console?

Comment: Can you share full html and javascript for the page?

Comment: Have you finally sorted this out? Because I have no new ideas.

Comment: Yes, i've [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35192325/2996624) my own question with what i came up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
        setTimeout(function(){
        hasFocus=false;
    },500, function() {hasFocus=true;});
```

Just add this: f*unction() {hasFocus=true;}* to the end of setTimeout function. Or create a function that sets hasFocus variable to true and call this function when the setTimeout function is completed.

You can read more about setTimeout function there: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/

EDIT: Oh, and if this method wouldn't work, then the Nikolay is right! :)

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, can you please show me a working demo?